# complex number with absolute and algebra

Tags: complex-numbers

Question 
if $|x+ i y-1|=|x+ i y-2 i|$ , where $x$ and $y$ are real, express $y$ in terms of $x$

My Solution: 
+/- $(x+ i y-1)=x+ i y-2 i $

case 1:

$(x+ i y-1)=x+i y-2 i $

$-1=-2 i$  (invalid)

case 2:

$$-(x+ i y-1)=x+ i y- 2 i\\
1+2 i = 2 x + 2 y i\\
2 x=1  \\         
x=0.5\\
2 y=2\\              
y=1$$

But the question wants to express  $y$ in terms of $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb R$.

So, 
$$\begin{align}|x+iy-1|=|x+iy-2i|&\Rightarrow  |(x-1)+iy|=|x+(y-2)i|\\&\Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{x^2+(y-2)^2}\\&\Rightarrow (x-1)^2+y^2=x^2+(y-2)^2\end{align}$$

Comment: by arranging and isolate y, i found

Comment: y = x/2 + 0.75 , Thank you for the starter :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a(n arguably) far better way of looking at this than using algebra... first of all if $w$ is a complex number then $|z-w|$ is the distance from $z$ to $w$. Note $|z|=|z-0|$ is the distance from a complex number $z$ to the origin. If you draw a little triangle and invoke Pythagoras you will see that

$$|z|=|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\neq \pm z.$$

Here you are talking about complex numbers/points in the complex plane $x+iy$ such that

$$|z-1|=|z-2i|\Rightarrow \text{dist}(z,1)=\text{dist}(z,2i).$$

If you ever did some technical graphics you would have discovered that the points that are equidistant from $1$ and $2i$ comprise the *perpendicular bisector* of the line segment from $1$ to $2i$.

At this point you should actually draw a picture of the complex plane with $1$, $2i$, the midpoint and this perpendicular bisector...

This perpendicular bisector is a line that goes through the midpoint of the line segment from $1$ to $2i$. Can you find the midpoint?

Can you find the slope of the line segment from $1$ to $2i$... your line will be perpendicular to this so...

Comment: that explained to me why my answer is wrong... quite confusing because of the absolute. Thanks a low

Answer (score 0):

Completely wrong. If $z, w$ are complex numbers, then $|z|=|w|$ **does not** imply that $z=\pm w$. For example, $|i| = 1 = |1|$.

I advise you to look into your lecture notes and find out what the absolute value of a complex number is. You almost certainly said something about that in your classes.

Comment: isn't absolute means can be either + or -

Comment: @lolisme Well, is the absolute value of $i$ equal to $+$ or $-i$?